# Create Widget in QMainWindow and load to ScrollArea

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I tried to create a Mainwindow with an slot, which creates a Widget and loads it to the ScrollArea in the Mainwindow. This doesn't work, so I tired to create the Widget in the constructor of the mainwindow and I always get errors and don't know why.. so what's the right declaration of the Widget?

```
#include <QtGui>


class Mainwindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Mainwindow(QMainWindow *parent = 0);

public slots:

private:
    QScrollArea *List,*Sublist,*Overall,*Settings;
    QLabel *label_title;
    QPushButton *bn_exit,*bn_list,*bn_overall,*bn_settings;
};

//! ------------------------------------- Mainlist -------------------------------------
class Sublist : public QWidget{
 Q_OBJECT
private:
    QLabel *title;
public:
    Sublist(QWidget *parent = 0);
};
```

and .cpp

```
Mainwindow::Mainwindow(QMainWindow *parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {

    this->resize(1024,576);
    //this->setWindowFlags(Qt::Popup);
    QPalette palette;
    palette.setColor(QPalette::Background, QColor(16,16,16));
    this->setPalette(palette);

    Sublist SecondList;

    //! [Set ScrollAreas]
    List = new QScrollArea(this);
    List->setGeometry(0,60,200,456);
    List->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);

    Sublist = new QScrollArea(this);
    Sublist->setGeometry(200,60,824,456);
    Sublist->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
    //Sublist->setWidget(SecondList)

}

//! ---------------------------------------- MainList------------------------------------------------------
Sublist::Sublist(QWidget *parent){
    resize(1200,1200);
    title = new QLabel("Title",this);
    title->setGeometry(1120,1120,40,90);
}
```

Comment: Does your file with the Mainwindow class include the declaration for the Sublist class?

Comment: yes, they are both in the same header

Comment: Just checking. This problem is not related to Qt directly. There is something you are missing which can't be determined solely from what you have provided here. You have an implementation for Sublist right?

Comment: edit-> now this is all relevant code i tried to get working but how can i create a Sublist-Widget e.g. in the constructor of Mainwindow as shown above. this is my main problem.
"Sublist SecondList;" does not work. What am i doing wrong?
thx for your help

Comment: Sublist = new QScrollArea(this); ... i think here lies the problem. You want to add the widget to your ScrollArea... so maybe Sublist = new QWidget(List) would be what you want?

Comment: ok problem is solved... i was so stupid and mixed up Sublist of ScrollArea and the Sublist Widget, both with the same name
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have played around with your code a bit, noticed a few things:

In class ***Mainwindow*** you define your ***QScrollArea*** variables:

```
QScrollArea *List,*Sublist,*Overall,*Settings;
```

You define a variable named ***Sublist*** of type ***QScrollArea***, but you also have a class of the same name:

```
class Sublist : public QWidget
```

Probably would be a good idea to change the variable names for your scroll areas:

```
QScrollArea *list, *subList, *overall, *settings;
```

Next, in the constructor for class ***Sublist*** you pass a pointer to the parent class but never assign it to your base class. You also have a QLabel widget that never is placed anywhere. What seems to be needed is a layout for your custom widget.

The ***Sublist*** class could be something like this:

```
//.h
class Sublist : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Sublist(QWidget *parent = 0);

private:
    QLabel *title;
    QVBoxLayout *layout;
};

//.cpp
Sublist::Sublist(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent) {
    resize(1200,1200);
    title = new QLabel("Title");
    title->setGeometry(1120,1120,40,90);

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(title);
    setLayout(layout);
}
```

The ***Mainwindow*** class something like this:

```
//.h
class Mainwindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Mainwindow(QMainWindow *parent = 0);

private:
    Sublist *secondList;
    QScrollArea *list, *subList, *overall, *settings;
    QLabel *label_title;
    QPushButton *bn_exit,*bn_list,*bn_overall,*bn_settings;
};

//.cpp
Mainwindow::Mainwindow(QMainWindow *parent) : QMainWindow(parent) 
{
    this->resize(1024,576);
    QPalette palette;
    palette.setColor(QPalette::Background, QColor(16,16,16));
    palette.setColor(QPalette::Foreground, QColor(255,255,255));//set text to white
    this->setPalette(palette);

    secondList = new Sublist(this);

    //! [Set ScrollAreas]
    list = new QScrollArea(this);
    list->setGeometry(0,60,200,456);
    list->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);

    subList = new QScrollArea(this);
    subList->setGeometry(200,60,824,456);
    subList->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
    subList->setWidget(secondList);
}
```

Im still not 100% sure this is what you where trying to achieve with this code, but I hope that I have helped you to resolve some of the issues in your current implementation.

Comment: you were right, the name of the class and variable were the same, this fixed the problem. thank you!